# Shrink child element relative positioned when the parent/browser shrink, with parrent using overflow

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

In the code below I have the code for a carousel.

Only a part of the images are shown(`container`) and the div that contains all images(`items`) is moved left/right using javascript.

It is possible to shrink the images if the browser window shrink `the container` becomes smaller

The number of images(`item`) is not fixed.

```css
.carousel {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0 1.5rem;
  position: relative; }
  .container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; }
  .items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.2s; }
  .item {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 9.375rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    transition: 0.2s;
    width: 9.375rem; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="carousel" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item" data-carousel-item="">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-carousel-item="">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-carousel-item="">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-carousel-item="">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-carousel-item="">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-carousel-item="">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-carousel-item="">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-carousel-item="">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-carousel-item="">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-carousel-item="">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using rem as your quantifier which is based on the font-size of your root element but I don't see you adjusting anything about fonts based on media queries. If you aren't specifically needing exact measurements like 100x100 then I would recommend using viewport quantifiers instead as these values change when your browser shrinks. I added a flex-wrap property for looks you can remove it and add back the overflow if you wish

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
.carousel {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 1vw 1vw 0 1vw;
  position: relative; }
  .container {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1vw 0;
    position: relative; }
  .items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap : wrap;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0; }
  .item img {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10vw;
    margin:1vw;
    transition: 0.2s;
    width: 10vw; 
 }
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6rvqag25/2/)